# Is there a simple way to generate API documentation from express-gateway services?

Tags: node.js, swagger, documentation, swagger-ui, express-gateway

Is there a simple way to generate API documentation from express-gateway services?
For example using swagger?
In the traditional way documentation is generated based on function's annotations, in express-gateway
APIS are defined in gateway.config.yml file and swagger don't know how to handle that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. Documentation requires much richer information than exists in Express Gateway yaml files, and the schemas describing the EG files don’t allow for additional information.

Ideally, there would be a tool that could process Swagger/OpenAPI specs and create Express Gateway configuration files, but I have not found any yet.